# How to mock service's response functions in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, mocking

So, in the test I already provided a mocked class for the AuthService

```
    { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthServiceMock }
```

This mocked service has an **isAuthorized()** function, that always **return true**;

And, in the spec, that look like this

```
it('init root with LOGIN PAGE if is authenticated, () => {

    expect(comp['rootPage']).toBe(LoginPage); // true!

});

it('init root with WELCOME PAGE if is not authenticated, () => {

    // Here I need to change the result of isAuthorized()
    // so inside the AuthServiceMock returns false
    expect(comp['rootPage']).toBe(WelcomePage); // false :(

});
```

EDIT: Added the full code of the describe

```
describe('Component: Root Component', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [MyApp],

            providers: [
              { provide: AuthServiceProvider, useClass: AuthServiceProviderMock },
              ConfigProvider,
              StatusBar,
              SplashScreen
            ],

            imports: [
              IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
            ]

        }).compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyApp);
        comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

    it('initialises with a root page of LoginPage if not authorized', () => {

        expect(comp['rootPage']).toBe(LoginPage);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really missing a lot of information here, but let me try to help.

Hopefully AuthServiceMock.isAuthorized is actually a jasmine spy already. This could be done when defining the class:

```
class AuthServiceMock {
  isAuthorized = jasmine.createSpy('auth.isAuthorized').and.returnValue(true);
}
```

If this is the case, and `isAuthorized` is a spy, then you can *change* the return value of your spy in your second test as follows:

```
it('init root with WELCOME PAGE if is not authenticated',
  inject([AuthService], (mockAuthInstance) => {
    mockAuthInstance.isAuthorized.and.returnValue(false);
    expect(comp.rootPage).toBe(WelcomePage);
  })
);
```

In this example, we have used the predefined injection rules and injected the mock service directly into our test.

If `isAuthorized` is NOT already a spy, then you can make it a spy in the test, as follows

```
it('init root with WELCOME PAGE if is not authenticated', 
  inject([AuthService], (mockAuthInstance) => {
    spyOn(mockAuthInstance, 'isAuthorized').and.returnValue(false);
    expect(comp.rootPage).toBe(WelcomePage);
  })
);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, the problem is that I dont have an mockAuthInstance at this scope. I am testing app.component.ts, wich one injects the AuthService internally.

At this scope, I only have comp and fixture variables. I will edit the main question and add the full code example. Thanks!

Comment: That is what the `inject()` methods do.  They will inject the SAME THING into your test.  In both of my examples above, there is `inject([AuthService], (mockAuthInstance} => {` after the test name (`it('init root with...'`)